# Is it possbile to edit files in old git commits and how?

Tags: git

Lets say I jave a git repo with commits

```
HEAD
commit999: Edit file999
commit998: Edit file998
...
commit3: Edit file3
commit2: Edit file2 and file1
commit1: Edit file1
```

I realized that file1 should not have been edited in commit2. I want to revert the change on file1 in commit2, but I don't want make a new commit for this revert.

Is it possible to do what I want? And if so, how can I do it?

(Only I use this git repo. So I don't care any dirty things, e.g., `push -f origin master`)

Comment: Read about [`git rebase --interactive`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#git-rebase--i)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by "amending revision 2" and then cherry-picking everything done on top of it.... something like this:

`git checkout commit2
git checkout HEAD~1 -- <path-to-file1> # checkout file1 as it was on the previous revision
git commit --amend --no-edit # create a _new_ revision
git cherry-pick commit2..commit999 # use old rev IDs for commit2 and commit999
git checkout -b new-branch # create and checkout new branch if you feel like it`

That should work.